# uiautomatorviewer text box, what does it do?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

In the uiautomatorviewer (the one that comes with android sdk) window , there is a textbox in the upper left corner (on top of the heirarchy view). What is it for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a search box. You can enter text to search for and then move to next or previous result with the little arrows.

Yep, ugly UI.